How to properly test washer/dryer supply hoses for leaks?
I set up some new hoses for a washer dryer (with steam) and finally got it to stop leaking with the water supply turned on. (waited about 30 mins) I even ran a small load to be sure it wouldn't leak.
After pushing everything back in the closet I just realized I never ran the dryer's steam functions to check for leaks. If the supply hoses doesn't leak when water is turned on is it safe to conclude it won't leak when running the steam dry?
I'm guessing running loads or testing cycles is redundant since the initial installer skipped those steps, but I'm just a bit worried since I had issues just getting the hoses to not leak when the water supply was on.
Hoping I can save some headache of removing the door and pulling everything out again!

approximately 50 million washers are connected in the US by screwing them into the fittings and moving on.

If the hoses don't leak when they are under pressure...they don't leak under pressure.
The steam function of my dryer only uses water supplied by the user in a tray.
It has no source of water from the washers hoses. So the dryer steam function would be totally unrelated to the washer hoses.
If your set up is different, the hoses would still be under pressure while delivering water for steam and if not leaking when the service valves are open they should not be leaking when delivering water for anything.

Thanks that makes a ton of sense, in my head I was imagining water running through the hoses would put more stress on the connections or something. My setup is the latter where the cold hose splits to the dryer and washer.
